# Why msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail doesn't work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sp-send-dbmail

I am facing a very peculiar issue regarding **msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail**

**What works**:

I am using msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail to send emails from different stored procedures. **It works**. No problems.

**What not works:**

Now when I put it in an **SQL JOB** then it doesn't work i.e. sending to smtp server (gmail) but smtp throws error i.e. Message blocked.

It only happens when I send from **JOB** from the same server but it works when I used it in stored procedures or manually using static values.

**What I have checked so far:**

I have checked, the job runs. It works but smtp throws an error:

**Message blocked**
*Your message to abc@gmail.com has been blocked. See technical details below for more information.*

Why ?

Job step's code:

```
IF EXISTS( select *  from MC_Complaints.dbo.Complaints cs where cs.OverDue= 1 AND ISNULL(EmailSent,0)= 0)
Begin
    Declare @Codes varchar(max)
 Set @Codes= (select
   distinct  
    stuff((
        select ', ' + cs.Code
        from MC_Complaints.dbo.Complaints cs where cs.OverDue= 1 AND ISNULL(EmailSent,0)= 0
        order by cs.Code asc
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as codeslist
from MC_Complaints.dbo.Complaints cs)


Declare @Body varchar(max)
Set @Body= 'Overdue complaints: '+ @Codes

exec MC_Complaints.dbo.SendMail @Body, 'Overdue complaints'

Update Complaints
Set EmailSent=1
where OverDue=1 
End
```

SendMail sp code:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
                            @profile_name='CMS',
                            @recipients=@EmailAddresses,
                            @subject= @Subject,
                            @body= @Body
```

Update:

If it was about permissions then it would have not sent it to Gmail. and I checked log, it shows email has been sent from the sql server but gmail fails to send further.

Update:

Tt happens when I send it from my other server, not from others but again the problem is by gmail that blocks the message.

Comment: What credentials is the job running under?

Comment: I'd take a look at the permissions of the user that is running the job; might not be permitted to access a remote network resource (the mail server)

Comment: @SchmitzIT: basic

Comment: But i guess it has nothing to do with permissions, since it sends it smtp but not further. The message is thrown by gmail

Comment: @CaiusJard: ummm. If it was about permissions then it would have not sent it to gmail. and I checked log, it shows email has been sent from the sql server

Comment: What are the technical details below that it claims to provide?

Comment: @CaiusJard: these: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596?visit_id=1-636330240861776511-1748565236&rd=1

Comment: it gives me this link but nothing seems to violate it

Comment: @SchmitzIT:  any solution ?

Comment: Not really, no. The issue seems to be at gmail, rather than SQL Server

Comment: It seems that Google somehow "sees" that mail comes from Sql Server Job. This in turn, raises suspicion of being ddos attack or spam, because of the mass and automatic nature of jobs,,

Comment: @SchmitzIT then why doesn't it cause any issue if I send it using a stored procedure or manually ?

Comment: @TSion.D.P: there must be a solution then ?

Comment: Did you try to contact Google for support ?

Comment: @Covert - No idea, and with the information supplied, it's not possible for us to figure out

Comment: No, but I'm in the middle of trying to contact MS for issue and that's really not easy. Even thought I have MSDN subscription from the company I work for ..

Comment: I mean It is not easy to contact the giants, But If we all stay quiet how will they know somethings wrong? ..

Comment: Do you get the same error when attempting to send to a non-gmail email address?

Comment: @LewsTherin: oh yes, it happens

Comment: Have you seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42529416/4416750)? Also [see this](https://www.restorebin.com/message-blocked-gmail-rejected/). Finally, I would check the email address that it is sending to is valid (look at the value of `@EmailAddresses` very carefully). Hope one of these helps.

Comment: @LewsTherin yes man, I did check this and none of them works. Yes, I checked emails addresses. They are fine but I noticed that it happens when I send it from my other server, not from others but again the problem is by gmail that blocks the message.

Comment: @SchmitzIT  it happens when I send it from my other server, not from others but again the problem is by gmail that blocks the message.